# Tabview in android..?

Tags: android, android-tabhost, tabwidget, android-tabactivity, android-tabs

I am developing an app where i am using tabwidget with 2 tab views. When the app is visible on screen, in first tab some data needs to be displayed in listview which i gets it from database. If the data is empty in listview by default second tab needs to be visible. 
**when the activity starts if the list is empty i want to start the other tab. if list is not empty the present tab needs to be visible..**
The below image gives some more detailed information about my question.

[image: First Tab with list view empty]

[image: Second Tab]

Here as per the above images when app is visible to the user for first time, the data will be empty. so, i want to display AddGroup Tab to add groups. **How is it possible to focus on Add Group Tab if list is empty in Groups Tab...**

Comment: Just trying to clarify what you want: you want to start on the other tab depending on if the list is empty or not when the activity starts(resumes)?

Comment: when the activity starts if the list is empty i want to start the other tab. if list is not empty the present tab needs to be visible..

Answer (score 3):

Setting the currently viewed tab can be done with

```
myTabHost.setCurrentTab(tabPos);
```

How you get to this TabHost object depends on where you are initialising the list: if it is done in the parent activity, (which extends TabActivity), you can use

getTabHost().setCurrentTab(tabPos);

If you need access to the TabHost from inside another activity (ie. when your tabs are activities) or View implementation (inside the ListView), add a method to your parent Activity that can be called by the classes in it, or objects that have a reference to it. Put this

```
public void switchTab(int tabPos){
    getTabHost().setCurrentTab(tabPos);
}
```

in the parent activity, and then use something of the form

```
((MyParentTabActivity) MyChildTabActivity.this.getParent()).switchTab(1);
```

to access it, depending on where you want to switch it from.

Comment: actually i am initializing tabview in Group.java which extends tab activity and as per the the above pictures Groups tab is one activity and Add Groups tab is other activity. here i am initialising the list in Groups tab. so, as per your code where i need to add the following code in my following activities..

Comment: That is the situation this code is used for - add the switchTab method to your Group.java, and use the line below to access it, replacing MyParentTabActivity with Group, and MyChildTabActivity with GroupsTab